# How to use params with slashes with Sinatra?

Tags: ruby, parameters, routes, sinatra

Playing with [sinatra](http://www.sinatrarb.com/), I'm stuck on a little problem : when I use params with slashes, it confuses the router engine. So is there a nice way to handle this kind of param without having to encode it ?

The code looks like

```
get 'add/:url' do
   #....
end
```

And I intend to get something like /add/http://sctackoverflow.com/ working

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Did you try to use splat parameters?

Something like:

```
get '/add/*' do
  protocol = params[:splat].first
  address = params[:splat][1..-1].join('/')

  url = protocol + "//" + address
end
```

Answer (score 3):

thank you, I haven't heard about splat parameters and it works perfectly for this case. Indeed, I've looked into the documentation and I found even shorter using capture parameters and regular expressions :

```
get %r{/add/(.+)} do
  url = params[:captures]
end
```

Answer (score 2):

or use:

```
url = request.fullpath[5..-1]
```