# Sinatra and question mark

Tags: ruby, get, sinatra, parameters

I need to make some methods with Sinatra that should look like:

> http//:localhost:1234/add?string_to_add

But when I declare it like this:

```
get "/add?:string_to_add" do
...
end
```

it doesn't see the `string_to_add` param.

How should I declare my method and use this parameter to make things work?

Comment: Have you seen this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/529065/how-to-use-params-with-slashes-with-sinatra?

Comment: this solution doesn't work when I need '?' instead of '/' befor '*'

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In a URL, a question mark separates the [path](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.3) part from the [query](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.4) part. The query part normally consists of name/value pairs, and is often constructed by a web browser to match the data a user has entered into a form. For example a url might look like:

```
http://example.com/submit?name=John&age=93
```

Here the path section in `/submit`, and the query sections is `name=John&age=93` which refers to the value “John” for the `name` key, and “93” for the `age`.

When you [create a route](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html#Routes) in Sinatra, you only specify the path part. Sinatra then parses the query, and makes the data in it available in the `params` object. In this example you could do something like this:

```
get '/submit' do
  name = params[:name]
  age = params[:age]
  # use name and age variables
  ...
end
```

If you use a `?` character when defining a Sinatra route, it makes part of the url optional. In the example you used (`get "/add?:string_to_add"`), it will actually match any url starting with `/ad`, then optionally another `d`, and then anything else will be put in the `:string_to_add` key of the params hash, and the query section will be parsed separately. In other words the question mark makes the preceding `d` character optional.

If you want to get the ‘raw’ text of the query string in Sinatra, you can use the [`query_string` method of the `request` object](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html#Accessing%20the%20Request%20Object). In your example that would look something like this:

```
get '/add' do
  string_to_add = request.query_string
  ...
end
```

Note that the route doesn’t include the `?` character, just the base `/add`.

Answer (score 0):

You should declare it as:

```
get "/add?:string_to_add?" do
...
end
```