# Sinatra URL Matching with question mark?

Tags: ruby, sinatra

Is there a way to match urls with Sinatra using question mark?

```
get '/:id?inspect' do
  # ...
end

get '/:id?last' do
  # ...
end

get '/:id' do
  # ...
end
```

I tried escaping the question mark `\?`, regex etc, but none of those worked.

I don't want to retrieve the value of `inspect` or `last`. I only want to know if they were supplied in the url.

Is that possible?

Comment: I don’t really understand – are you asking the same as http://stackoverflow.com/q/15774187/214790 ?

Comment: The question is almost the same, but the correct answer in the link above, only explains how URL routing works, it doesn't answer the question. I would like to know if it is possible or not and how. I know that the question mark is a URL separator, I tried to escape it, but didn't work.

Comment: So you want to route based on the contents of the query string? Like checking `request.query_string` in an `if` statement, but using separate routes?

Comment: Yeah! I don't want to do the `if`. I would like to use the Sinatra Router Handler to do that for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can’t directly do what you want. When describing the route, Sinatra treats `?` as defining an optional parameter, and doesn’t provide a way to escape it.

In a url a `?` separates the path from the query string, and Sinatra only uses the path when matching routes. The contents of the query string are parsed and available in `params`, and the  raw string is available as `request.query_string`.

Your url scheme seems rather unusual, but one possibility if you want to avoid checking the `query_string` in the actual route could be to create a [custom condition](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html#Conditions) to apply to the routes, and check in there:

```ruby
set(:query) { |val| condition { request.query_string == val } }

get '/:id', :query => 'inspect' do
  # ...
end

get '/:id', :query => 'last' do
  # ...
end

get '/:id' do
  # ...
end
```

Answer (score 0):

A standard route is not defined by query parameters and should not be. Why don't you use a `if` construct on the `params` in the `get /:id` route?

I also suggest that when you want to set a query parameter in the request you set it like this: `/:id?inspect=true` (provide a dummy value)

Comment: Why not? I'd prefer to have a specific methods (blocks) handling the parameter than an explicit `if` inside a global method. The `?last` and `?inspect` aren't resources, they don't need to be have a specific url, they are only options for the same resource URL, but as they have different representations in my use case, I would rather to have specific methods (block) and let Sinatra handling the conditions based on the url.

Comment: This is a comment to aledalgrande. There is a reason for omitting the "=true" part, since it is simpler to type for the user. I just had a use case for "?"; I wanted to add: "to_dna?source", to show the source code in-page. The to_dna conversion already worked, so I wanted a simple user-explanation here. Using a URL such as "to_dna?source=true" would not make sense. Although I suppose we may not refer to exactly the same thing, since your use of : probably refers to the in-ruby handling rather than the param passing - but that is what the threadstarter referred to. I have a similar use case.