# Sinatra with optional query parameters

Tags: ruby, regex, routes, sinatra

I want to create a Sinatra API route with optional query parameters.I'm able to add the query parameters as follows

> %r{^/mysql/data/(?)/start_time=(?\w*)/?}

But the route corresponding to the above route is like "/mysql/data/:name/start_time=:start_time"

I need the query parameters as optional and to be declared in URL format.

Eg:

> /mysql/data/:name?start_time=:start_time&end_time=:end_time

Is there any way in Sinatra to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate.  See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15774187/sinatra-and-question-mark

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Quoting from the Sinatra Docs:

```
# Routes may also utilize query parameters:

get '/posts' do
  # matches "GET /posts?title=foo&author=bar"
  title = params[:title]
  author = params[:author]
  # uses title and author variables; query is optional to the /posts route
end
```

In your case simply use `/mysql/data/:name`, any query parameters will be available via `params` automatically.