# Cannot get parameter URL in Sinatra from my GET request

Tags: ruby, url, sinatra

I have this Ruby Gem that i m trying to use, that takes a URL as a parameter. Im using Sinatra to create a web service to this service. I dont know either Sinatra nor Ruby ..
So if i do a:

```
  curl -i -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X GET http://localhost:4567?http://www.myhostserver.com/mattdaemon
```

I want my Ruby app to parse http://www.myhostserver.com/mattdaemon and pass it to my Ruby Gem.

Here is my code:

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'rubygems'
require 'myrubygem'
require 'rack'
require 'rack/server'


get '/:id' do
#  widget = myGem::Profile.get_profile("#{env['QUERY_STRING']}")
# widget = myGem::Profile.get_profile("#{params[:id]}") 
  set :my_url, "#{request.env['QUERY_STRING']}"
widget = myGem::Profile.get_profile(":my_url]}")
  return status 404 if widget.nil?
  widget.to_json
end
```

Commented out are my attempts .. I always get a 404 back .. How do i even get relevant error messages to understand what's going on ?

Thanks!

Comment: Is there a reason that you use `-H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json"`?

Comment: well, i just wanted to enforce the response to be json. But yeah i guess all of this is optional.

Answer (score 1):

> A bit confused on that point

I guess mainly you need to understand the difference between the url path with parameter and the query string.

Let's assume you have a parameter `name` with the `value` mattdaemon. The next assumption is that you using GET instead of POST.

**Query String**

This is kind of what you have right now. The Query string is the thing which looks like this: `?param=value&param2=value`

code example

```
get "/" do
     puts params[:name]
end
```

curl

> curl myhostserver.com:4567?name=mattdaemon

`params` parse your query string an more for you, so you can easy access the values.

What you doing here is a GET on / with a query string.

**Route patterns**

Sinatra allows you to build REST like urls with parameters in it.

```
get "/:name" do
    puts params[:name]
end

get "/user/:name" do |name|
    puts name
end
```

curl

> curl myhostserver.com:4567/mattdaemon
>   curl myhostserver.com:4567/user/mattdaemon

As you can see `params` does here also the most work for you.

Comment: Thanks - so in my case, if i were to use a route pattern/URL resource instead of a URL parameter like i have right now, how should the code be like - something like this ?: 
  get '/user/:name' do |name|
  widget = myGem::Profile.get_profile("#{name}")
  ..
end

Comment: yeah, I would use route pattern for this

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this: [Sinatra and question mark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15774187/sinatra-and-question-mark) helped me.
I did:

```
get '/' do
  string_to_add = request.query_string
  widget = myGem::Profile.get_profile("#{string_to_add}")
  return status 404 if widget.nil?
  widget.to_json
end
```

With a call as:

```
curl -i -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X GET http://myhostserver.com:4567?mattdaemon
```

What is odd is the URL i m passing - there is no parameter name .. If instead i used http://myhostserver.com:4567/mattdaemon (i.e., as a resource) that doesnt work. A bit confused on that point, but eh, it works.