# An Encoded forward slash is being handled as if it was un-encoded - Sinatra

Tags: ruby, url, sinatra

I have a Sinatra route like

```
get 'check/:input' do |in|
   ##Do stuff in here
end
```

but when I put a string in :input that contains a forward slash, such as "abcde/12345" or even encoded like "abcde%2F12345", Sinatra is thinking I am trying to reach

```
check/abcde/12345
```

and I hit the standard Sinatra 404 page. How do I get around this? I need the slash in the input variable, so I can't simply trim it out or anything like that. Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Can you not delimit with a pipe | ? Or maybe you could use multiple parameters, `check/:input/:input2`.

Comment: What do you mean exactly?

Comment: I don't want two parameters, I want "abcde/12345" to be a parameter

Answer (score 1):

This is done deliberately as part of [`rack-protection`](http://rubygems.org/gems/rack-protection)’s [path traversal protection](https://github.com/rkh/rack-protection/blob/v1.5.3/lib/rack/protection/path_traversal.rb#L34).

To disable it you can do

```
set :protection, :except => :path_traversal
```

Answer (score 0):

This is probably what you are looking for. Props to the person who answered it here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/529172/78551

Basically you are confusing the router. You need to pull it in as separate inputs and join them back in the action.